# C# how to pass objects from loop to collection

Tags: c#

I have a loop which creates objects and draws them out just fine but what I can't figure out is how do I pass it into AddRange {param1, param2,param3, and so on}?

```
Dictionary<String, Parameter> param = new Dictionary<String, Parameter>();           
foreach ( string parameterName in myParams)
{                                
    param[parameterName] = new parameter();                     
    param[parameterName].Description = parameterName;
}
Parameters.AddRange(new Parameter[] {"param[parameterName],param[parameterName],..and so on"});
```

Comment: why bother with AddRange? You could just do Add inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add them by using the `Dictionary`'s `Values` property and `ToArray()`:

```
Parameters.AddRange(param.Values.ToArray());
```

`Values` is a property of `Dictionary` that gives you the collection of values (Parameters) inside that `Dictionary`.

With the `ToArray()` extension method you can convert this collection into an array (`Parameter[]`) which is what `AddRange` expects.

---

Alternativly, you could add those parameters already inside your `foreach` loop with single `Add()` calls:

```
Dictionary<String, Parameter> param = new Dictionary<String, Parameter>();           
foreach ( string parameterName in myParams)
{                                
    param[parameterName] = new parameter();                     
    param[parameterName].Description = parameterName;
    Parameters.Add(param[parameterName]);
}
```

Comment: Getting Error- Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, DevExpress.XtraReports.Parameters.Parameter>' to 'DevExpress.XtraReports.Parameters.Parameter'

and

'Dictionary<string, Parameter>.ValueCollection' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and no extension method 'ToArray' accepting a first argument of type 'Dictionary<string, Parameter>.ValueCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Index fixed the the first line, it just does't like param.Values."ToArray()" in AddRange

Comment: @user2224135 you only need one of the two ways! `ToArray` is a linq extension. maybe you missed a reference or need to use `Values.OfType<Parameter>().ToArray()`

Comment: Indeed! Was missing: 
`using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 0):

you can cast to list the values and then use add range,

```
Parameters.AddRange(param.Values.ToList())
```